# How to build specific lazy loaded angular module

Tags: angular, module

We have large project with multiple lazy loaded modules and I am looking for a solution to build specific module to save compile time and resources.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think It's possible. If you add modules for every component and import them into usage page one by one, you can save compile time.

Answer (score 0):

For now, That feature is not implemented in Angular, So it's not possible.Maybe the will implement it in the future